# How might I create a menu with images like that used on photobucket?

Tags: javascript, menu

Please take a moment to look at [photobucket.com](http://photobucket.com/)'s navigation menu.

Do you know how I can achieve this look with the images next to the dropdown items in the menu.  Do you know of any tutorials for this?

Comment: emu! http://img68.exs.cx/img68/822/emu.jpg

Comment: @jason - that's hilarious! Unfortunately, i edited out the joke. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time and check out [CSS*play*'s menu section](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/). You'll find more classy menu styles than you could possibly imagine, all configurable (and most implemented) via HTML and CSS - so images are as easy as anywhere else on your page.